# Conditionally index document for elasticsearch using Tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using [tire](https://github.com/karmi/retire) with rails and elasticsearch. I want to conditionally add a document to the index if a boolean flag on my model is true. I'm sure this is straight forward but I can't seem to find out how to.

Answer (score 1):

I worked out solution. I removed this callback include from my model:

> `include Tire::Model::Callbacks`

and implemented my own callback like this:

```
after_save do
  if live == true
    self.index.store self
  else
    self.index.remove self
  end
end
```